# Creating a hidden buffer

Tags: buffers, vimscript-python, hidden-buffers

I know that with commands like `sbuffer` you can create a new buffer and display it in a split window, and commands like `enew` can create a new buffer in the current window. But is it possible to not display the buffer in any way but just create a hidden buffer right away?

My use case is that I have a python class that should return a `vim.buffer` object to be processed. The display happens differently depending on conditions in the calling object. So I need a buffer that I can load, and write stuff into (it's a buffer not associated with any file, so it's a `nofile` buftype), but that is not displayed until I command to load into the current or some other window.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not aware that you can create a hidden unnamed buffer.

But you can create a hidden (even unlisted) buffer with some fancy name and use that.

In VimScript:

```
let g:myscratch = bufnr("my-fancy-name", 1)
call setbufvar(g:myscratch, "&buftype", "nofile")
```

The first line returns the buffer number for the buffer named "my-fancy-name". If the buffer does not exist, it is created as hidden, *unlisted* buffer. So you don't see it with `:ls`.

The second line sets the buffer as `nofile`.

The buffer is created, but (for whatever reasons) you cannot write to it. You first have to activate it for a moment: <sup>[I didn't find another way to make it "writable".]</sup>

```
let curbuf = bufnr("")
execute g:myscratch . "buffer"
execute curbuf . "buffer"
```

If you do this short switch of buffers in a function, you won't see it (screen is not updated).

After that you can write to it with `setbufline(g:myscratch, ...)` and `appendbufline(g:myscratch, ...)`.

To bring it to view:

```
execute g:myscratch . "buffer"
```

To finally delete it use `bwipeout`:

```
execute g:myscratch . "bwipeout"
```

Comment: Additionally i think bufadd can buffers without switching to them.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble it`s the command `:badd`, but then you need a following `bufnr()` to get the number for `appendbufline()` etc.

Comment: ah that makes sense i forgot about the writing part

Comment: Can you link or explain why the short switch won't actually appear on the screen? When is the screen actually updated then?

Comment: @SalmonKiller Redrawing the screen is a expensive operation, so Vim will try to do it only when needed. I'm not aware where this is documented. But perhaps someone else knows more.

Comment: @Ralf huh, in that case, maybe it's a bit easier to create a new window with `new` and then close it? I tried and there is no flickering to the window is not being redrawn, and then the buffer appears in the `ls` list. What do you think of this approach? I'll also be doing this in python, so the buffer object is easily accessible through `vim.current.buffer`.

Comment: @SalmonKiller If this works for you, it is just fine.

Comment: to make the buffer writable, `call bufload(curbuf)` would be sufficient